# How can I execute a command when my laptop is docked?

Tags: xrandr, laptop, dock

I have a Lenovo X220 with a dock and external screen. Right now I have to launch a `xrandr` shortcut by hand to use the screen I want, depending on the situation.

For example :

- Docked : `xrandr` with external screen output
- Not docked : `xrandr` with laptop screen output

I was wondering how to do this automatically, maybe with help of `lsusb`'s output? When the laptop is docked it lists `Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Plus Series 3`, is there a way to detect that and then run the corresponding `xrandr` command?

Or maybe there's another simpler solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`udev`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev):

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/<priority>-<name>.rules

ACTION=="add", BUS="usb", SYSFS{serial}="<serial-number>", NAME="<name>", RUN="/your/xrandr/script"
```

(e.g. `<priority>` might be `50` and `<name>` `docked-monitor`)

Where the `SYSFS` and `NAME` settings come from `lsusb`. Other options to target the particular device (your dock) are available, see the man page (linked above) for what's most convenient to you.

Then reload to take effect:

```
$ udevadm control --reload-rules
```